# swift insert new static cells tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

want to add new cells.  how can i do this?
please help!
i try

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 1 {
        return 3 + eventDates.count
    } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        eventDaysVisible = !eventDaysVisible
        tableView.reloadData()

        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: eventDates.count + 3, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    for day in eventDates {
        print("OBJ: \(day)")
    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

i have 3 static cells and the new cells needs to insert after the first if i switch a button.

```
var eventdates =  Friday, Saturday, Sunday
```

hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var cellCount = 1

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}


extension ViewController:UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellCount
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let eventDates = ["1", "2", "3"]

        var indexPathsArray = [NSIndexPath]()

        for rowCount in 0 ..< eventDates.count {
            indexPathsArray.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: rowCount, inSection: 0))
            cellCount += 1
        }

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsArray, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths takes an array of the indexPaths you want to add. It looks like you will want to pass in 3 separate indexPaths in this example.

Comment: I updated my response above to show how to create the array if indexPaths and pass it in, but Im not sure what you are expecting in your layout so it may not work until you sort that out (do you have 2 sections, 1 row in each section? which section/row selection should handle the row insertion? in your code numberOfRowsInSection is adding row counts to section 1, but is then adding new rows to section zero.)

Comment: ok - Ive edited the answer again to show a basic working example. You can use the same approach.